# Resuable component only to be re-used a certain number of times

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have part of my application that I want the user to be able to invite other users to the application, dependant on their pricing plan the number of invites they can send changes.

I am wanting to have a button 'Invite Another' that when clicked adds another `InviteForm` component to the current screen, but I want to stop the user inviting users one they hit their pay plan threshold?

Is this possible?

Here is my attempt,

```
class InviteWizard extends Component {

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            invites: [],
            threshold: 5,
            filled: 1
        }
    }

    handleAddInvite = () => {
        // if (this.state.invites.length <= this.state.threshold) {
        //     this.state.invites.push(<InviteForm addInvite={this.handleAddInvite} />);
        // }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.state.invites.push(<InviteForm addInvite={this.handleAddInvite} />);
    }

    render() {

        return (
            <div className="InviteWizard">
                {this.state.invites}
            </div>
        )
    }

}
```

The threshold is current hard coded for now.

Comment: Just check a current account against your threshold--but you'd need to retrieve that threshold from the server side. As Strebler states, however, you still need to validate the number of invites on the server side: anything on the client side can be reverse-engineered (with varying levels of difficulty) so no matter *what* you do on the client side you still have to check on the server.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you would still have to check this server-side as everything can be manually changed client-side.

I recommend that you don't use your state to store JSX elements, but instead keep the bare minimum of informations in your state, for example how many invitations the user wants to send (aka how many times he clicked on 'Invite another' + 1). Then in your `render`, you read that value to generate a certain number of `InviteForm`s.

You check that the number of forms doesn't exceed the threshold in the event handler of your 'Invite another' button.

Comment: http://funnyanimalphoto.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/bear_polar_relaxing-660x510.jpg?bd03d3

Answer (score 0):

You can dynamically add your `InviteForm` according to `invites` state.

Think about a situation when a user can invite **X** friends,
in this case, you will be holding a state with **X** similar forms without any reason.

> Take notice that `filled === invites.length`, and deciding adding new form is checking `threshold - invites.length !== 0`

### Using Hooks:

```js
// const threshold = 5;

function InviteWizard({ threshold }) { // threshold as props
  const [invites, setInvites] = useState(1);

  const handleAddInvite = () =>
    threshold - invites !== 0 && setInvites(invites + 1);

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={handleAddInvite}> Invite </button>
      {Array.from(Array(invites), () => (
        <InviteForm addInvite={handleAddInvite}/>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

This `hooks` [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/rlwywzkp6m?fontsize=14).

### Using Class:

```
const threshold = 5;

class InviteWizard extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { invites: 1 };
  }

  handleAddInvite = () => {
    if (threshold - this.state.invites !== 0) {
      this.setState({
        invites: this.state.invites + 1
      });
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.handleAddInvite}> Invite </button>
        {Array.from(
          Array(this.state.invites),
          () => (
            <InviteForm addInvite={this.handleAddInvite}/>
          )
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

This `Class` [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/ry2m8q75o?fontsize=14).

For dynamic `threshold` pass it using `props`.